# How to login to Google Drive via the API Keys

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I do as described in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_apikeys):

```
#google key
API_key = "xxxxx"
#creating an instance of the class
drive_service = build('drive', 'v2', developerKey = API_key)
#get a list of child folder in
children = drive_service.children().list(folderId='yyyyyyy', **param).execute()
```

**An error:**

> An error occurred: https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/yyyyyyy/children?alt=json&key=xxxxx
>   returned "Login Required">

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a minimalist version that demonstrates folder interrogation using GDrive API V3.

```
import httplib2
import pprint
import sys
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

def printChildren(parent):
  param = {"q": "'" + parent + "' in parents and mimeType != 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"}
  result = service.files().list(**param).execute()
  files = result.get('files')

  for afile in files:
    print('File {}'.format(afile.get('name')))

API_KEY = 'XXXXXXX' # get from API->Credentials page in console.cloud.googl.com
FOLDER_ID = '1bWJ18tyq1h-ABQT79SgTsJQFRCIIblHS' # NOTE: folder must be publicly visible when using an API key.
service = build('drive', 'v3', developerKey=API_KEY)
printChildren(FOLDER_ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `children` seem to be limited to *OAuth2.0*, here is an example program for use with `API_KEY` that I wrote for myself. Using this you can recurse through a folder and do most of the stuff you would do with `children`.

```
import httplib2
import pprint
import sys
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

# The API key of the project.
API_KEY = '<yourapikey>'

def createDriveService():
    """Builds and returns a Drive service object authorized with the
    application's service account.

    Returns:
        Drive service object.
    """

    return build('drive', 'v2', developerKey=API_KEY)

service = createDriveService()
def recurse(parent):
    def recurseFolders():
        result = []
        page_token = None
        while True:
            param = { "q": "'" + parent + "' in parents and mimeType =  'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'" }
            if page_token:
                param['pageToken'] = page_token
            files = service.files().list(**param).execute()
            result.extend(files['items'])
            page_token = files.get('nextPageToken')
            if not page_token:
                break

        for folder in result:
            recurse(folder.get("id"))
        
    def printChildren():
        result = []
        page_token = None
        while True:
            param = { "q": "'" + parent + "' in parents and mimeType != 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'" }
            if page_token:
                param['pageToken'] = page_token
            files = service.files().list(**param).execute()
            result.extend(files['items'])
            page_token = files.get('nextPageToken')
            if not page_token:
                break
        
        for afile in result:
            # Cannot use webViewLink, because it's only valid for static html content
            print afile.get('title') + u':' + u'"' + afile.get("webContentLink") + u',"'

    recurseFolders();
    printChildren();
recurse('<folder_id>')
```